# Jetty spring profile programmatically

Tags: spring, jetty, profiles

I'm looking for a way to set spring profile in jetty programmatically so that the application that the war file on the server used the given profile, this is my code:

```
final WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
context.setLogUrlOnStart(true);
context.setWar("target/deployables/myapp-rest/myapp-rest.war");
context.setContextPath("/" + TEST_APP_CONTEXT);
context.setParentLoaderPriority(true);
server.setHandler(context);
server.start();
```

I tried a couple of things but none of them seem to work... I need to pass -Dspring.profiles.active=myProfile

Answer (score 0):

This is tested with Jetty 9.3 but `webdefault.xml` seem to also be available for lower versions (it's placement might be different though).

Go to `$JETTY_HOME/etc` and open `webdefault.xml`. Search for `context-param` in the file. Add this code somewhere below:

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>spring.profiles.default</param-name>
   <param-value>prod</param-value>
</context-param>
```

This will work if your `web.xml` (in the `your-app.war` file) doesn't contain this `context-param`.

Otherwise you could also use `override-web.xml` ([docs](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/override-web-xml.html)) but you would need to configure it in `jetty-web.xml` and `jetty-web.xml` must be bundled inside the war... So YMMV, but I didn't want to change my war and `webdefault.xml` is an easier solution for me.